# Поиск человека по лицу в массиве фотографий

Tags: распознавание-образов

Известны ли вам публичные инструменты (фреймворки, etc) для серверного ПО, способные найти в базе фотографий такую, на которой был бы изображен человек из тестовой фотографии (на которой запечатлено лицо искомого человека)?

Буду благодарен за помощь в поиске подходящего инструмента.

**P.S.** Не важно какой язык программирования.